# How to return the value for function in Crystal report using Crystal Syntax

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I tried to make the function in Crystal report using Crystal Syntax (not Basi syntax). As Basic syntax, at the end of function, there is a function return the processed value of function but in Cyrstal Syntax, there is no return keyword to do it, please let me know how could I return the processed value from a function which was written by Crystal syntax.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just type the variable name in the last line.

```
numbervar x := 1;
x;
```